# Does God fight?

Tags: gods

I am new to the Hindu religion but I have been studying the Master Course Trilogy for several years. I strive daily to uphold my Dharma and resolve my Karma. Thus far everything that I have read on Hymalayan  Academy teaches that everything is Siva. When I read elsewhere such as this blog site, I see all these battles of Shiva  with Krisna and all the many stories of having a wife . I thought that all these frailties were inexperienced souls who are living in lower chakras. How does any of this make sense.

Comment: The Puranas where these stories occur are not Sruti (truths revealed by God - Vedas - Upanisads), they are Smriti (written by man). The Puranas can be taken as myths to teach lessons, they do not have to be taken literally.

Answer (score 3):

The problem in your chain of reasoning is the following:

- "I thought that all these frailties were inexperienced souls who are living in lower chakras." is false as far as the Gods are concerned.
- "everything is Siva" and "Siva fights some asura" are not contradictory. God created the world out of himself (viz puruShasUkta) for his enjoyment (viz the famous shruti "sa eko na ramate") and in doing so, takes up the tasks of regulating (creating, maintaining and destroying) this creation.